# geos_ts_c.cpp + spatialite Error

Tags: spatialite, sqlite, geos

select distance(T1.Geom,T2.Geom) as Distance, T1.POI_ID, T2.LINK_ID
from temp1 as T1, temp2 as T2 where T1.POI_ID = T2.POI_ID AND Distance < 100

temp1 having point geometry
temp2 having line geometry

While I running above query through C# program I am getting Error ::

Assertion failed !

Program: ...
File: geos_ts_c.cpp
Line : 3472

(look attached snapshot)

I am having database in .db format.
I am using SQLlite and spatialite for gis functionality.

From code ::

I am loading spatialite.dll and then with sqllitecommand running query..

ExecuteStatement("select load_extension('spatialite.dll')", con);
SQLiteCommand selectCommand11 = new SQLiteCommand(selectSQL10, con);
SQLiteDataReader dataReader10 = selectCommand11.ExecuteReader();

anybody have idea why I am getting this error ? and how can i resolve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Final Comments ::

```
Hello Sandro,

Before some minutes I found one inlogical solution. (But can't
confirm because I am doing Testing right now)

Previously while each query run I was making connection to database
and closing it after use. (To save the garbage)
And each time loading 'spatiallite.dll'.
```

*The solution most usually adopted by C or Java apps is exactly
the one to open a DB connection immediately (at the very beginning
of your own code), then closing this connection just before
terminating the program and exiting.
And to always use/re-use the same connection for all SQL queries
executed by your code.
Opening a new connection surely has a cost; thus perfoming many
times a connect-disconnet cycle will certainly have a very bad
performance impact.
That's not all: each SQLite connection has its own page cache;
repeatedly creating and destroying the connection will obviously
negate any possible "optimization effect" coming form using a
page-cache.
A possible explanation about the many "memory issues" you were
experiencing:
- C# is based on garbage collection
- but C components (as the sqlite / spatialite / GEOS DLLs)
will anyway continue to use good, old, plain dynamic memory
allocations based on classic malloc/free explicit calls
and is exactely on the basis of this very simple considerations
that I'm not a fan of C#; because this way you'll mix more
or less at random very different memory allocation schemas,
may be creating fatal "corrupted" conditions.
- repeatedly opening/closing the connection could effectively
create chaos between conflicting memory allocation strategies.*

```
**I removed 'middle connection opening and closing, and also loading of
extension'.**
```

*yes, this definitely seems to be the optinal approach.
bye Sandro*